# Does publish to IIS in production safe

Tags: .net, iis, windows-server-2012, webdeploy

I have an application hosted on several servers on AWS with a load balancer.
I push updates to the servers with Microsoft Web Deploy.

Lets say I want to push an update to all the servers.
Should I remove the server from the load balancer before deploying to it?  What will happen to requests currently being processed by the application pool and what will happen to new requests coming to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "safe". From the standpoint of the state of your current deployment, nothing will be affected.  From a data integrity standpoint, this process may not be safe. When the `.dll` for your project is replaced in the server, the application pool recycles almost immediately.

The result of this is that all current process is terminated with impunity. The more users that are using the system, the more prevalent the result of the undefined behavior will be. The main thing that gets taken out are database connections, and often a user will be in the middle of posting and everything will look okay but only part or none of their transaction will complete.

Ajax requests will spin indefinitely at times as a result of this as well. Basically it just nukes everything that is currently running and there is no grace period or forgiveness.

To get around this, large services will often issue a warning.

> The server will be restarting in 15 minutes.

In order to facilitate this, it helps if there is a switch you can change in the application itself somewhere which basically returns a page indicating that the server is offline by some sort of action at the global level when the request is first encountered. Turn this on after 15 minutes, and let it run for as long as it may have taken for a very long request to be serviced. This should be a default value somewhere (I know for most places it is as long as 2 minutes, and sometimes as short as 30 seconds).

After waiting a small time to ensure all previously sent requests were actioned before your switch, push your update. If the switch is a static value defaulted to off, simply pushing the new version will reset the static value, and everything will come back on once the new `.dll` is compiled and the application pool is restarted.